# Python, Linux: How to execute multiple commands using pysftp

Tags: python, linux, fabric, paramiko, pysftp

Here I am trying to execute commands on remote server and getting back its output, for every command, but it need a saperate connection, but if I create saperate connection or session, its responding me very slowly,

The code that I am trying run is, But its not working :

```
import pysftp
import paramiko

commandlist = ("ls", "uname -a","whoami")
ans = []
sftp = pysftp.Connection("localhost",username="root",password="123456",port=22)
for i in commandlist:
    try: 
        out = sftp.execute(i)
        ans.append(out)
    except (paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException,paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException), e:
        ans.append(e)
return ans
```

working code is:

```
import pysftp
import paramiko
commandlist = ("ls", "uname -a")
ans = []
for i in commandlist:
    try: 
        sftp = pysftp.Connection("localhost",username="root",password="123456",port=222)
        out = sftp.execute(i)[0]
        ans.append(out)
    except (paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException,paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException), e:
        ans.append(e)
return ans
```

now here its creating connection for every command to execute,
please help me, let me know if this can be done by other liberary like paramiko or fabric and how.

Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Also, why are you using an sftp client to execute commands?  paramiko can create an ssh session directly I believe, and that would be more appropriate if you aren't trying to transfer files, though `ls` is appropriate for either

Comment: I am checking exception Handler here but its not working, i am adding two images here please check why it is not working,, Here my exception handler is working 
[link]
(https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipP-N0JbmBSve0kdYu48ax6nk2kRdd-Vlo4Lv-1A8nZQERb6dqsNQVYirCnNCKsmhA/photo/AF1QipM_fOe14ma01fc5mZIyaioHaYnpMTFb32_qoyQt?key=dTNCMXIwR191d3NKRXdOdnViQkQ4MHdmUkVGUDZR)

Bt not here
[link]
(https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipP-N0JbmBSve0kdYu48ax6nk2kRdd-Vlo4Lv-1A8nZQERb6dqsNQVYirCnNCKsmhA/photo/AF1QipMABjeE9uXgrkzSRm7SdvDksW8wae3k8yRtffJd?key=dTNCMXIwR191d3NKRXdOdnViQkQ4MHdmUkVGUDZR)

Comment: Well as the traceback shows, you're not trying to do the Connect inside a `try...except` block, so you'll never be able to handle the exception.  For future reference when asking questions, it's usually helpful to include the text of the traceback in the question, and as text, not an image.

Comment: Thanks @eric.. i will follow your advice.